# Replace line of file

Tags: bash, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make an version increment script. So I have an file `manifest.json` that has predefined lines (e.g. 45 lines).

`$1` parameter is file name 
`$2` parameter is new version numbers (e.g. `0.3.5.29`)

Input is like `$ BumpVersion.sh manifest.json 0.15.2.34`

I need to replace for example `"version":    "0.2.0.1",`
with `"version":    "0.2.1.0",`

-- EDIT --
Oh and i forgot, version isn't always `0.2.1.5`, it can be `0.3`

I know line number and line content, I basically just need to replace numbers.
 I'm doing this in Git-Bash on Windows and it should work on Linux and Unix if possible.

(I never worked with bash script, but I need it for cross-platform support)

Comment: How many times you bump that version up? I have some chrome-extensions myself. And I just do it manually. It's just one place to update. It doesn't deserve a shell script to do it. IMO

Answer (score 2):

Should be a simple `sed` script. (I'm assuming your quotes are required):

```
file="VERSION.json"
new_version="0.2.1.0"
sed -i "s/\"version:\" \"[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\"/\"version:\" \"$new_version\"/" $file
```

However, I don't like this. Instead, you should have a template, and rewrite the template by replacing a known string like `%VERSION%`.  For example, you have a file called *VERSION.json.template*:

```
file="version.json.template"
new_version="1.2.2.1"
sed "s/%VERSION%/$new_version/" > "${file%.template}"
```

That's cleaner and simpler to implement.

The `${file%.template}` removes the `.template` suffix from the file name. If you're using a version control system, you're not saving a new version of the `version.json` file with each compile. Instead, you simply make it part of your standard build routine which should include a *clean* mechanism to remove the unneeded `version.json` file.

If you use a build system like [Ant](http://ant.apache.org), you could use its various tasks (like a copy/filter task) that would build and copy this file elsewhere for your webpage.

Comment: The thing is that file isn't used for VCS but for Google Chrome Extension - manifest.json file. I don't have to change version of this file on every build only for builds that are released.

Oh and i forgot, version isn't always `0.2.1.5`, it can be `0.3`

Comment: The sed string could be changes to `s/version: .*/version $version/` which would allow any version number match, but it could cause trouble if there is more than one line with the word `version` in it. I recommend the template approach and use `%VERSION%` which is easier to keep unique in your file.

Comment: The current answer will not work, because the regex: "version:\"  would match against the text "version:", but of course the JSON keyword is "version":.   Move the colon to just after the escaped double-quote and it's good.  (I figure someone is going to copy-paste and adapt this, then wonder why it fails).

Answer (score 0):

Your BumpVersion.sh script can look like this

```
#!/bin/sh
sed -i "/\(\"version\":\).*/\1 \"$2\"/" "$1"
```

Comment: What does \1 stand for cause I get error on char 19 "unknown command : '\'"

Comment: did you cut and paste exactly? `\1` holds the string `"version":` because there's no reason to type it twice in that sed script.

Comment: I doesn't work...
sed: -e expression #1, char 19: unknown command: `\'

Comment: Please paste the exact command for which you're getting that error.

Comment: And what is the content of incVersion.sh?

Comment: This could also be an issue with the version of sed (-i is supported these days on OSX, but might not be on other UNIX). Just replace the \1 with the "version": string, since you want to keep that text (and just replace what's after it).